# How to access OS X recovery mode when I lost the password?

Tags: osx-mavericks

I did not write down my new password after changing it. To reset the MacBook Pro with Mavericks I tried Recovery HD by holding down <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> at restart, but all I get is a lock with a white line window to enter a password, which I do not have.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Enter recovery mode again by holding Command-R at startup.

Go to the Utilities menu on top and then to Terminal.

In terminal type in `resetpassword` then hit Enter.

You should be presented with a reset password window there. Select the OSX drive you were using and then the associated user account.  Type in the new password and you're good to go.

After your done and click save, you will be prompted with a message saying that the password was reset but your keychain is not.  Just click OK and restart your computer or do whatever you wanted to do.